# Deploying non http based service in the cloud

Tags: azure, cloud

Is it possible to deploy service in the cloud , which does not use standard http protocol for providing services ?.
Basically I have requirement to write service which does not use http to exchange messages between client/server. It is traditional client server application , which uses non standard protocol running on port other than port 80. 
Can we deploy this kind of application in the cloud ?.

What is the recomended approch for such kind of services ?.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as long as no firewalls get in the way "the cloud" per se doesn't require port 80 nor does it require HTTP.  For example it's pretty common to deploy DNS services (by UDP or TCP on port 53).  All you need to do is check with your "cloud supplier" what ranges of ports can be made available (by removing whatever firewalls might otherwise be in the way); different suppliers will have different policies.

Not really a programming problem, BTW: strictly a system/network administration one.

Answer (score 0):

XML-RPC may be what you're looking for.